# How can I pause a progressbar in JAVA?

Tags: java, mobile, android

I have a login form in Android and I want when I do it login a progressBar circular icon appears of loading and then it should be hidden when next Intent is opened.when I click the login button, the code executes so fast that it hides my progressbar, even the code of visibility false is after the new intent object creation, but it's not working, let me know how to handle progress bar in this case.
Can everyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please show what code you've tried so far.

Comment: Please post your code here so that we can improve it for you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's working? A ProgressBar should show until some background process is done, then the next Activity should show. If you're doing a series of startup tasks, you should either show them as they occur, or not show any of them until they're all done. A ProgressBar shows that some operation is going on in the background.

If you want to indicate that the app is following a series of steps, each of which has its own Activity, then the UI for each Activity should show this. However, there's little need to show anything in the foreground unless you want to allow the user go skip a step, go back, or go somewhere else.